# Touchpad won't work after kernel update to 4.15.0-72-generic

Tags: 18.04, kernel, touchpad

The touchpad on my laptop stopped working after an automatic kernel update to 4.15.0-72-generic.  My only work-around at the moment is to start up with the  previously installed kernel (4.15.0-70).  Where should I report this bug to have any hope of it being fixed, and which information do I need to include?